# Im trying to retrieve the data from realtime Database in Firebase Swift 4

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, swift4

```
@IBAction func onEqualPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let securityPin = value?["SecurityPin"] as? String ?? ""
        let digit = self.outputLbl.text
        let user = User(username: securityPin)

        if digit == (securityPin) {
            self.showRealMenuScreen()
        }

        if digit != (securityPin) {
            self.stayOnCalculator()
        } else {
            self.processOperation(operation: self.currentOperation)
        }


    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

I keep getting this error:

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments on: User(username: securityPin)

Comment: `let user = User(username: securityPin)` It looks like this `User` object doesn't expect an argument.

Comment: What if i don't use : let user = User(username: securityPin) can i still retrieve the data thats my real probelm

Comment: You're not using `user` anywhere else in the code, so it seems a useless line to begin with. Keep in mind that I have no idea what `User` is in this context, so can't know what it is supposed to accomplish.